# VBA Application.Match finds a header, but it cannot be used when trying to select that column

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'm trying to select a column that has been found based on header name.
Header is found in column 19 but I am unable to select that column due to an error.
I have no idea what is wrong with that.

```
Dim h As Integer, LastHeader As Integer, LCol As Integer, LR As Long


With Sheets("Headers")
Dim RespondentCol As String
Dim x As Variant
LastHeader = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For h = 2 To LastHeader
    x = .Cells(h, 3).Value
    RespondentCol = Application.Match(x, AONCSATTracker.Sheets("Phone Formulas").Rows(1), 0)
Columns(RespondentCol).Select

Next h

End With
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the intention? You are declaring variable `RespondentCol` As String and then trying to select column which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dim RespondentCol As String` but number of column needs integer

```
Dim h As Integer, LastHeader As Integer, LCol As Integer, LR As Long


With Sheets("Headers")
    Dim RespondentCol As String
    Dim x As Variant
    LastHeader = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For h = 2 To LastHeader
        x = .Cells(h, 3).Value
        RespondentCol = Application.Match(x, AONCSATTracker.Sheets("Phone Formulas").Rows(1), 0)
        if IsNumeric(RespondentCol) then
            Columns(CInt(RespondentCol)).Select
        end if
    Next h

End With
```

Add short variant

```
Dim h as Long
With Sheets("Headers")    
    For h = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row              
        .Columns( _
            Application.Match(.Cells(h, 3).Value, AONCSATTracker.Sheets("Phone Formulas").Rows(1), 0) _
            ).Select
    Next h
End With
```

Comment: Instead of casting the string to an integer declare the `RespondentCol` as `Long`.

Comment: yes, is better way ) but it's only the part of code, may be....